# How can I reset the password of my workspace account in Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I've gotten locked out of my Oracle APEX workspace. It is hosted locally, not in the Cloud.

The reset password won't help, as the account is tied to an email address of an employee who left.

The DBA has the credentials of an account of a different workspace.

Is there any procedure to reset this account's password?

Comment: "... email address of an employee who left." - is that e-mail address still *alive*? I mean, does it accept mails? Could you contact that employee and ask them to let you know the new password once it is sent to them? Or, if it is an e-mail address your organization takes care about, talk to sysadmins and ask them to *revive* it just for this purpose and deactivate it back afterwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have Database access?
If yes, you can see the Apex table (it's schema named with the version like apex_210100) and under that, you will find WWV_FLOW_FND_USER table.
Update that table's row with user_name = 'youruser' filtering.

i.e:

```
set ACCOUNT_LOCKED = 'N',FAILED_ACCESS_ATTEMPTS = 0, web_password = '12345',LAST_FAILED_LOGIN = NULL
where user_name = 'test@test.com';
commit;
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know that! I don't need it, but - thank you for the info from me as well!

Comment: brilliant, thanks @Cengiz, however there is a pr for this i believe

Comment: what is pr? @Oguen

Comment: a procedure created by APEX developers for that type of needs

Comment: I have no idea of that, if you know which one and how to use it, can you share that knowledge to us?

Comment: `APEX_UTIL.RESET_PASSWORD` can be used to reset a password. You will need to set your workspace first though. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/aeapi/RESET_PASSWORD-Procedure.html#GUID-D7416D24-1DBB-4784-960A-86E0EEC6F801

Answer (score 3):

There shouldn't be a need to update an internal apex table via sql. You can edit the users for any workspace from the **INTERNAL** workspace - that workspace is only used for instance administration. The default account for that workspace is **ADMIN** but you can created other users in that workspace as well. If the password for the admin account is lost it can be reset using the `apxchpwd.sql` script.